# Ripple emulator fail

Tags: cordova, ripple

when I try to emulate by ripple my cordova application ripple fail and on console I can see message:localhost:4400/config.xml not found. I've created and built correctly my cordova app, I think.

When ripple open browser appear an alert with something like this:

```
gap:["PluginManager","startup","PluginManager1671388621"]
```

[image]

if I click annul, show me message "ripple has fail to emulate....zombie apocalypse"
if click ok go in loop

Comment: Can you describe *how* it failed? What do you see in the browser?

Comment: @RaymondCamden added more info

Comment: Ok, to be clear, you are using the Ripple command line, right? Not the old Chrome extension?